# shift column data if column1 is empty and make other column NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with multiple column. I want to write UPDATE query using PHP and MYSQL which shifts the column data if only Col1 data is NULL.
For Example:

**Orginal Table**

+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|      Col1      |      Col2      |      Col3      |      Col4      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     NULL      |     dat1       |      dat2      |      dat3      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     NULL      |     dat1       |      NULL     |      dat3      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     dat0      |     dat1       |      NULL      |      dat3      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     NULL      |     NULL      |      dat2      |      dat3      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+

The Output table will be below

+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|      Col1      |      Col2      |      Col3      |      Col4      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     dat1      |     dat2       |      dat3      |      NULL      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     dat1      |     dat3       |      NULL     |      NULL      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     dat0      |     dat1       |      NULL      |      dat3      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|     dat2      |     dat3      |      NULL      |      NULL      |

Comment: why `dat3` was moved on second row, bot was not moved on third?

Comment: @sectus: Because `Col1` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Seems like you have a denormalized data structure and want to do something that would be much easier if the data were stored in rows instead of columns.

Comment: :D Use next time the code button instead of thousand `&nbsp;` ;)

Answer (score 3):

When `col1` is `NULL`, you seem to want to move all the values to the left.  You can do this with brute-force logic, which isn't that bad for four columns:

```
UPDATE table
  SET Col1 = coalesce(Col2, col3, col4),
      col2 = (case when col2 is not null then coalesce(col3, col4)
                   when col3 is not null then col4
              end),
      col3 = (case when col2 is not null and col3 is not null then col4 end),
      col4 = NULL
  WHERE Col1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Ya actually I have 9 column in the table I just put 4 just to get the idea. But it seems like the update query is getting too long. Please give me idea on this or other way round with more than single query.

Comment: @user3591167 . . . Your question is about 4 columns, not 9 columns.

Answer (score 1):

A php script that will work for an arbitrary # of columns but it runs 1 update per row, so it will be slow if you have lots of rows.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Col1 IS NULL";
$rs = mysqli_query($query);

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {

    $non_null = array_filter($r);
    $update = array();

    foreach($r as $key => $value) {        
        $update[$key] = current($non_null);
        next($non_null);
    }

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE myTable SET ";
    $comma = '';

    foreach($update as $key => $value) {
        if(false === $value) {
            $updateQuery .= " $comma $key = NULL ";
        }
        else {
            $updateQuery .= " $comma $key = '$value' ";
        }
        $comma = ',';
    }

    $updateQuery .= " WHERE ";
    $and = '';

    foreach($r as $key => $value) {
        if(is_null($value)) {
            $updateQuery .= " $and $key IS NULL ";
        }
        else {
            $updateQuery .= " $and $key = '$value' ";
        }
        $and = 'AND';
    }

    mysqli_query($updateQuery);
}
```

Comment: @user3591167 can you try again with the update? if it still doesn't work print $updateQuery

Comment: Instead of  
`while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {`

 I used  `while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {`
works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Phone1_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 1 THEN y.val END),
    Phone2_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 2 THEN y.val END),
    Phone3_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 3 THEN y.val END),
    Phone4_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 4 THEN y.val END),
    Phone5_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 5 THEN y.val END),
    Phone6_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 6 THEN y.val END),
    Phone7_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 7 THEN y.val END),
    Phone8_Business = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 8 THEN y.val END),
    Phone9_Cell = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 9 THEN y.val END),
    Phone10_Cell = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 10 THEN y.val END),
    Phone11_Cell = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 11 THEN y.val END),
    Phone12_Cell = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 12 THEN y.val END),
    Phone13_Cell = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 13 THEN y.val END),
    Phone14_Cell = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 14 THEN y.val END),
    Phone15_Other = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 15 THEN y.val END)
FROM #temp1 
OUTER APPLY
( SELECT
x.val,
rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn)
FROM
( VALUES 
(Phone1_Business,1), (Phone2_Business,2), (Phone3_Business,3), (Phone4_Business,4), (Phone5_Business,5), (Phone6_Business,6)
, (Phone7_Business,7), (Phone8_Business,8), (Phone9_Cell,9), (Phone10_Cell,10), (Phone11_Cell,11), (Phone12_Cell,12)
, (Phone13_Cell,13), (Phone14_Cell,14), (Phone15_Other,15)
) x (val, rn) 
WHERE x.val IS NOT NULL
) y 
GROUP BY 
#temp1.RecordID ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.